# Convert structure fields to arrays efficiently matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, structure, memory-efficient

I have a structure called `s` in Matlab. This is a structure with two fields `a` and `b`. The structure size is 1 x 1,620,000.

It is a very large structure (that probably takes half of the ram of my machine). This is what the structure looks like:

[image]

I am looking for an efficient way to concatenate each of the fields `a` and `b` into two separate arrays that I can then export to csv. I built the code below, to do so, but even after 12 hours running it has not even reached a quarter of the loop. Any more efficient way of doing this?

```
a = [];
b =[];
total_n = size(s,2);
count = 1;
while size(s,2)>0

    if size(s(1).a,1)
    a =   [a; s(1).a];
    end
    if size(s(1).b,1)
    b =   [b; s(1).b];
    end
    s(1) = []; %to save memory
    if mod(count,1000) == 0
        fprintf('Done %2f  \n', [count/total_n])
    end
    count = count+1;
end
```

Comment: Since you apparently don't care about empty fields, and from this example it looks like every field is a 2-by-n string array, you could do `a = [s.a]` and `b = [s.b]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
s(1) = []; %to save memory
```

ah, but such huge misunderstanding that comment is.

if `size(s)` is  1 x 1,620,000, you just suddenly forced the loop to do (under the hood, you dont see it)

```
snew=zeros(1,size(s,2)-1) # now you use double memory
snew=s(2:end)  # now you force an unnecesary copy
```

So not only does that line make your code require double the memory, but also in each loop, you make an unnecesary copy of a large array.

Just replace your `while` for a normal for loop of `for ii=1:size(s,2)` and then index `s`!

Now, you can see hopefully then why the following is equally a big mistake (not only that, but any modern MATLAB version is currently telling you this is a bad idea in your editor)

```
a=[]
a=[a;s(1).a]
```

In here in each loop you are forcing MATLAB to make a new `a` that is 1 bigger than before, and copy the contents of the old `a` there.
instead, preallocate the size of `a`.

As you don't know what you are going to put there, I suggest using a cell array, as each `s(ii).a` has a different length.

You can then, after the loop, remove all empty (`isempty`) cells if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it efficiently:

```
s= struct2cell(s);
s= squeeze(s);
a = a(1,:);
a = a';
a = vertcat(a{:});
b = a(2,:);
b = b';
b = vertcat(b{:});
```

Comment: Is `merge_keys` the same as `s`? `a = a'` doesn't do anything here, since `a` is a vector and later you do `a{:}`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thanks for pointing that out. For some reason the vertcat did not work without the transpose line before. Do not really know why.